# Aligned at the same margins acronym and listofsymbols

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, glossaries, acronyms

First of all, I know, that it would be much easier to use the `glossaries` package. However, maybe there is still a solution to my question. Here is a short MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{acronym}

%Symbolverzeichnis
\usepackage[final]{listofsymbols}
\renewcommand{\symheadingname}{Symbolverzeichnis}


\begin{document}
\section*{Abkuerzungsverzeichnis}
\begin{acronym}[EU-EHS]
\acro{EU-EHS}{Europäisches Emissionshandelssystem}
\end{acronym}
%Symbolverzeichnis
\opensymdef 
\newsym[Aufrechter Buchstabe]{AB}{\text{A}}
\closesymdef

\listofsymbols

\newpage
\AB
\end{document}
```

I am trying to align the list of symbols to the same position as the acronym package does. Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Comment: `listofsymbols` is an aged package, with no update since 2003. I suggest to use the much more up-to-date `glossaries` package, which allows for many customizations and can do both acronyms and list of symbols etc. You don't even need `acronym` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into `listofsymbolscode` there is a `\hspace*{\symindent}` for each symbol entry, i.e. a default indentation for symbols.

The user manual does not reveal anything about `\symindent`, but again looking in the package code, it is shown, that

```
\setlength{\symindent}{1.5em}
```

is the default value. Changing the length to `0em` removes the indentation.

Side note: I suggest to use the modern `glossaries` package instead of `listofsymbols`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{acronym}

%Symbolverzeichnis
\usepackage[final]{listofsymbols}
\renewcommand{\symheadingname}{Symbolverzeichnis}

\setlength{\symindent}{0em}

\begin{document}
\section*{Abkuerzungsverzeichnis}
\begin{acronym}[EU-EHS]
\acro{EU-EHS}{Europäisches Emissionshandelssystem}
\end{acronym}
%Symbolverzeichnis
\opensymdef 
\newsym[Aufrechter Buchstabe]{AB}{\text{A}}
\closesymdef

\listofsymbols

\newpage
\AB
\end{document}
```